# ng generate application to a specific folder (without projects folder)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I have a folder "dashboards". Inside that i'm trying to create applications using "ng g application promotions". But it creates inside projects/promotions. 
I also tried using "--flat". But it still creates folder. How to create without folder?

Comment: you can move the promotion folder to the root folder and update the paths in angular.json accordingly. It's the best practice to keep the applications in the projects folder.

Comment: I don't want the projects folder & instead of that i have "Dashboards". Under this all the application should come. Also, editing/configuring angular.json for every application is a pain, causes issues. Don't want to touch angular.json once set-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your angular.json, change the property value of `newProjectRoot` from `projects` to `dashboards`.

`"newProjectRoot": "dashboards",`

If you create any new application in the workspace, then the app will be generated inside the `dashboards` folder.

Comment: Oh! didn't see that. Thanks. Works.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ng new myApp --newProjectRoot=my_folder
```

where `my_folder` is needed folder name.

then check your `angular.json` file and you'll see:

```
"newProjectRoot": "my_folder"
```

`ng new` commands can be found [here](https://angular.io/cli/new)